how formula of "MSE" Mean Square Error equation can convert to weight formula
Could someone explain how the formula above has been transformed into the one below? I heard that by taking the derivative, we can arrive at it, but I couldn't find it in any book. Does anyone know how to convert the upper formula to the lower one?
enter image description here
search google. and use Chat gpt

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
